# TWAIN A4 does specificatoin obliged us to use left-upper corner as start coordinate

Tags: specifications, twain

I'm participating in the development of scan software. And I need to work with one strange scanner. It's default A4 region located not in the left-upper corner (it is in the middle). Does TWAIN specification accept this? Because, usually, if scanner is able to scan larger region than A4, A4 region is located in the left-upper corner of the entire area.

Answer (score 0):

According to the section **DG_IMAGE / DAT_IMAGELAYOUT / MSG_GET** of TWAIN Specification:

"The outline of the image is expressed by a “frame.” The Left, Top, Right, and Bottom edges of the frame are stored in pImageLayout->Frame. These values place the frame within the scanner.All measurements are relative to the scanner’s “upper-left” corner.Define “upper-left” by how the image would appear on the computer’s screen before any rotation or other position transform is applied to the image data. This origin point will be apparent for most Sources "